# Binary Tree Puzzle

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, puzzle

Recently I came across this interview puzzle.
Can Someone Explain me what this puzzle means..

**You are given a binary tree. A light source is placed on the right of the tree. Print the list of all the nodes over which the light is falling directly.**

Which Nodes will be shielded ?  It's obvious the right nodes will get printed but if the left subtree is greater, then we have to include a couple of extra test cases , right?

Correct me , If I'm wrong!

Comment: I imagine they want a list of all the rightmost nodes of the tree

Comment: What a vague interview question. Maybe they should have told us which nodes they wanted instead of having to have us visualize some data structure with a light source.

Comment: I have no idea what the question is asking. If I was in the interview I would've asked for more information or a diagram or something.

Comment: Why are people downvoting it? It seems an interesting puzzle though. Is it because it's lacking some info...that's the reason I asked it in first place

Comment: @psychoCoder people are downvoting, as this is not the best place for such hypothetical questions. SO is about programming questions with specific problems - this one is too broad for this site.

Comment: The only thing "puzzling" about this question is what the question writer was smoking before they wrote it.

Comment: It is not that hard: (R-to-L) inorder visit + a watermark for how deep you have visited before.

Comment: The interviewers  should have expressly set the geometry of their setting at least (but maybe they expected you to comment on that): light source positioned at 'infinite' distance, constant edge lengths, angle between  edges connecting a parent node to its children being constant over all nodes (say alpha), angle between parent-parent and parent-child edges either 180deg, 180deg-alpha, 180+alpha (depending on whether parent/child are left or right daughter nodes. Then apply the @wildplasser traversal

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. The rightmost subtree should be printed, and possibly some nodes of the tree that in the left subtree. In fact the rightmost node of every level of the tree should be printed. In the following example the nodes marked with an `x` should be the output

```
    x
   / \
  o   x
 / \
o   x
```

You could realize this with recursive backtracking, by traversing the tree and always taking the right path and print out the nodes you traversed.

If you reach a node withoud any children you go back to the parent node and continue on its left path until you reach a deeper level than before (here you start printing them out again) or until you reached a node wihtout children.

If you repreat this you will eventually get all the nodes that are touched by the light